# how to prevent adding new view object in listview when scrolling listview

Tags: android, listview

I have a linearLayout inner listview, inside linearlayout I have to add ImageView and TextView and it set in Adapter as much data I want to show.
it perfectly work until the list view scrolled.
when I scrolling the listView the object view increase every time I scroll.
this bellow my code

```
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chattemplate, null);
    }
    LinearLayout lin = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.linearChat);
    final ImageView img1 = new ImageView(context);
    final TextView tv1 = new TextView(context);
        tv1.setText(chat.getPesan());
        tv1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_corner1);
        tv1.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
        tv1.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        tv1.setMaxWidth(250);
        img1.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cservice));

        lin.addView(img1);
        lin.addView(tv1);

    return convertView;
```

Comment: As a side note, you are creating a new ImageView and TextView every time the getView() method is called. If your ListView contains more than ~7 items, this will be horribly inefficient and is likely not even necessary from what I can see. Also, consider using RecyclerView as ListView should be considered deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just remove views and then add new views.

```
LinearLayout lin = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.linearChat);
lin.removeAllViews();// here we remove all views before adding new views,
    final ImageView img1 = new ImageView(context);
    final TextView tv1 = new TextView(context);
        tv1.setText(chat.getPesan());
        tv1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_corner1);
        tv1.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
        tv1.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        tv1.setMaxWidth(250);
        img1.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cservice));

        lin.addView(img1);
        lin.addView(tv1);
```